Gutenberg / Wordpress: edit shortcode to only show posts of a specific year?
A client wants to show blog-posts of seperate years with a headline inbetween.
Right now we are showing all posts with this shortcode:
<!-- wp:ivory/posts-grid {"postsToShow":36,"order":"desc","categories":"25"} /-->

I tried to add
,"year":"2020" 


but that doesnt work. I couldn't find the source for all commands or a solution to add this filter of years.

I guess it's simple but i just couldn't find the right answer.
I would greatly apperciate a solution or a link where i can find the right knowledge to add this.
Thank you very much!

What is wp:ivory/posts-grid? any plugin?

it’s the Wordpress theme - creator doesn’t exist anymore so I can’t ask him… I was hoping that everything after that is a known syntax ?

You need to find this code and see what it does and what parameters it takes. If year or date_query is not there, modify this code so that it accepts those parameters and works properly.
